# JavaFX 8 passing Controllers to methods

Tags: javafx

An accordion in my GUI application has quite a few FXML controllers (each controls a single TitledPane). Within the appplication, these controllers need to talk to each other (and I've got that working). But now I want to have something a little more elegant and lean more about JavaxFX in the process.
So instead of this:

```
ToolbarViewController toolbarController;
DesignAreaController designController;
...
public void setToolbarController(ToolbarViewController toolbarController){
    this.toolbarController = toolbarController;       
}
```

etc. for each controller, is there a way of doing this with one method call? Something like:

```
public void setController(String id??, ???Controller controller){
    listOfControllers.getControllerById().setController(controller);
} // This makes no sense of course but illustrates my question
```

Comment: Can you check this out? This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22178533/communication-beetween-two-javafx-controllers

Comment: I have thank you, but that's mostly about communicating between controllers and that bit works fine for me.

Comment: Perhaps having all the controllers have references to each other is the real issue. Typically, they should all have access to a shared model and access the data in the model.